# Is getLastErrorCode() good API design for returning error codes?

Tags: api, oop, error-handling

What is the best practice regarding returning error codes?

Sometimes we meet situations where a class method operation is unsuccessful, but it is *not* exceptional. If the reason why it fails are varied, then we need a way to tell the caller why it has failed.

For example, I have `Actor::equipItem()` method that equips an item to an RPG character object. The reasons for failure could be:

- Character level is not high enough.
- Character class cannot equip that item.
- Character attribute is not sufficient (e.g. not enough strength).
- The item is already broken.
- The item is a two handed weapon and the character is already wielding a dagger.
- etc.

The way I see it, the situations above are not exceptional. I can implement `Actor::equipItem()` in two ways.

- First is returning `int` codes, like `0` for success and `1` for the level is not enough, `2` for wrong character class and so on.
- The second is returning boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and implementing `Actor::getLastErrorCode()` that the caller can inspect if it needs to provide a feedback to the user.

Which of the two is the best practice in terms of OOP and API design? Are there alternatives? Is there a best practice for handling error codes that are not exceptional situations?

Comment: If you're getting to the point where you're modifying the object graph, and *then* you find out the would-be graph is invalid, i'd call that pretty exceptional.  Personally, i'd break equipping an item into checkin whether you can, and then doing it.

Comment: This means implementing `Actor::canEquip()`, which I assume will mean returning `int` error codes to the caller. So the first one is the way to go for you?

Comment: I think so, yes.  Although i'd have `equipItem()` throw an exception if the item can't be equipped.  If the caller doesn't want exceptions, it can check beforehand, and if it doesn't care, it can still use either `canEquip` or the exception to find out what went wrong.

Comment: I agree with @cHao. If a method can't do what it says it will do, that's an exception. If you need to know why, you can catch the appropriate exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said, I agree with cHao that throwing exceptions is the right way to handle this. However, I wanted to comment on how you might decide to process all of those rules. This scenario is a perfect situation for a rules engine, using good ol' polymorphism. (Checking out the chain of responsibility (CoR) design pattern would be good for this.)

You could use a bunch of `if` statements in your method. Or, better yet, have each `if` check be its own class that implements something like IEquipItemRule:

```
public interface IEquipItemRule
{
    bool CanEquip();
}
```

Then, instead of an `if` statement, your consuming code can process all of the rules like this:

```
List<IEquipItemRule> equipRules = GetEquipRules();  // This is where the CoR pattern comes in

foreach (IEquipItemRule rule in equipRules)
{
    // Note: Instead of throwing immediately, you could collect all of the
    //       messages and return all of the failure reasons.
    if (!rule.CanEquip()) { throw new AppropriateException(rule.Message); }
}
```

The nice thing about this is that this check can be in its own method. So, if you want to check first to see if this method will succeed, the consumer can call the above code. And when the actual method runs, it can call this checking code as well.

Note: An example of an equipment rule might be something like this:

```
public class CharacterLevelRule : IEquipItemRule
{
    public bool CanEquip()
    {
        if (characterLevel <= necessaryLevel) { return false; }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: For rules that require outside information, you will need to provide it, however the information is varied. It could be a character level (int), a class type (object), a bool on whether or not the character has an off hand weapon equipped, etc. So I'm not sure if breaking it into a strict Interface is a good solution. However I do agree on your point on breaking it into two methods so that the checking method can be called independently.

Comment: Varied information is okay. And you would pass that into the CanEquip() method. This is why it's accepted as good practice to pass entire objects instead of pieces. For example, send Character instead of just his level. That way, each rule can pick and choose what it needs to make a decision. If you need many pieces to make a decision, those pieces can be wrapped in a container so you're still only passing one object (or very few objects).

Comment: After some thoughts, I think both of you are correct in this. There might be cases where checking if the operation is successful *after* the operation is more suitable (i.e. `getLastErrorCode()`), but having the check method allows for greater flexibility, and to me that means it's a better API design. I'm thinking of creating an `InventoryException` class that houses the error codes and acts as the exception to be thrown in inventory operations (equip, drop, move, remove, add).